# Grails Log4J Not Logging In Production

Tags: grails, log4j, tomcat6

I have a Grails 1.3.7 application and am trying to setup log4j for production in the configuration. The log4j settings were fine in development, but I can't get anything to show for production. I am trying to make a rolling file among other things, but I can't get anything to show. I even have the configuration at the "info" level so that I can ensure something will come through.  I don't see anything of interest in the tomcat logs on the server. Any ideas?

```
log4j = {
    def catalinaBase = System.properties.getProperty('catalina.base')
    if (!catalinaBase) catalinaBase = '.'   // just in case
    def logDirectory = "${catalinaBase}/logs"

    root { info "stdout", "roll", "errors" }

    // Log all at the error level
    info 'org.apache.',
    'org.tomcat.',
    'grails.app',
    'org.acegisecurity',
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet', // controllers
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', // GSP
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', // layouts
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
    'org.springframework',
    'org.hibernate'
    warn 'org.mortbay.log'
    warn 'grails.app'

    appenders {
        console name: "stdout", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n %-5p %m%n")
        file name: "errors", file: "pps-errors.log", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n %-5p %m%n")
        appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(name:"roll", datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd", file:"pps-rolling.log", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n %-5p %m%n"))

        environments {
            production {
                file name: "prod-errors", file: "${logDirectory}/pps-errors.log".toString(), layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n %-5p %m%n")
                appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(name:"prod-roll", datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd", file:"${logDirectory}/pps-errors-daily.log".toString(), layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n %-5p %m%n"))
            }
        }
    }

    environments {
        development{

            debug stdout:   'org.hibernate.SQL',
            'org.hibernate.transaction'//,
            //'org.hibernate.cache'
            //trace stdout: 'org.hibernate.type'
        }
        test {
            root { error "stdout", "roll", "errors" }
        }
        production {

            root {
                info "prod-roll", "prod-errors", "stdout", "roll", "errors"
            }

            info 'org.apache.',
            'org.tomcat.',
            'grails.app',
            'org.acegisecurity',
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet', // controllers
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', // GSP
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', // layouts
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate'
        }
    }

    debug 'grails.app.task'
    //grails = "debug"
    //StackTrace = "error,errors"

    //additivity.StackTrace = false
}
```

EDIT:

The catalina.out file in tomcat6 has the following:

> log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
>   (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader). log4j:WARN Please
>   initialize the log4j system properly.

**SECOND EDIT:**

I made a minimal configuration following Burt below to this:

```
log4j = {
    String logDirectory = "${System.getProperty('catalina.base') ?: '.'}/logs"

    info 'org.apache.',
            'org.tomcat.',
            'grails.app',
            'org.acegisecurity',
            'org.codehaus.groovy.grails',
            'org.springframework',
            'org.hibernate'
    warn 'grails.app'

    appenders {
        file name: "errors", file: "${logDirectory}/pps-errors.log",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: commonPattern)
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
                name:"roll", datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
                file:"${logDirectory}/pps-rolling.log",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: commonPattern))

        file name: "prod-errors", file: "${logDirectory}/pps-errors.log",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: commonPattern)
        appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
                name:"prod-roll", datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
                file:"${logDirectory}/pps-errors-daily.log",
                layout: pattern(conversionPattern: commonPattern))
    }

    root {
        info "prod-roll", "prod-errors", "roll", "errors"
    }
}
```

I still get the same message in tomcat and still no logging takes place. Is there something I have to do to setup tomcat for logging in this manner?

EDIT 3:
Output from App-Info. This does not have my custom appenders in it, leading me to believe that that is the problem. However, when I run the app in development mode, I can verify that the log files are in fact created:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">    <appender name="stacktraceLog" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
      <param name="file" value="/home/devon/Documents/SynaSync/Projects/ProjectPointSpread/Source/trunk/target/stacktrace.log"/>
      <param name="name" value="stacktraceLog"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="conversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x
- %m%n"/>
      </layout>    </appender>    <appender name="stdout" class="org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender">
      <param name="name" value="stdout"/>
      <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
         <param name="conversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %-5p %c{2} %x
- %m%n"/>
      </layout>    </appender>    <logger name="StackTrace" additivity="false">
      <appender-ref ref="stacktraceLog"/>    </logger>    <logger name="grails.app">
      <level value="WARN"/>    </logger>    <logger name="grails.app.task">
      <level value="DEBUG"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.acegisecurity">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.apache.">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.hibernate">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.springframework">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <logger name="org.tomcat.">
      <level value="INFO"/>    </logger>    <root>
      <level value="INFO"/>
      <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>    </root> </log4j:configuration>
```

EDIT 4: I am still having a problem logging in production. Now, when I use the below logging config and run it in debug mode, I can correctly see all of the appenders in the app-info tool. However, when I build the code for production the app-info reveals that the log4j.xml that would be generated is pretty much blank:

New config:

```
log4j = {
    String logDirectory = "${System.getProperty('catalina.base') ?: '.'}/logs"

    // For some reason the 'appenders' section had to come first and it messed everything up! Maybe it just 
    // needs to go before root
    appenders {
        console name: "stdout", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n %-5p %m%n")
        file name: "errors", file: "pps-errors.log", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n %-5p %m%n")
        appender new org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender(name:"roll", datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd", file:"pps-rolling.log", layout: pattern(conversionPattern: "%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n %-5p %m%n"))

    }


    root { info "stdout", "roll", "errors" }
    // Log all at the error level
    info 'org.apache.',
    'org.tomcat.',
    'grails.app',
    'org.acegisecurity',
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet', // controllers
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages', // GSP
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh', // layouts
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping', // URL mapping
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons', // core / classloading
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins', // plugins
    'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate', // hibernate integration
    'org.springframework',
    'org.hibernate'
    warn 'grails.app'
}
```

Output log4j.xml in Prod:

```
<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/" debug="false">
   <logger name="Test">
      <level value="ALL"/>
   </logger>
   <root>
      <level value="DEBUG"/>
   </root>
</log4j:configuration>
```

Comment: How do you run your app? Tomcat and deploy the grails application as war? Or are you using a different servlet engine?

Comment: @Stefan Armbruster - I do a grails prod war, then I put it in the tomcat webapps folder and restart tomcat. Also, I am editing above to add extra information. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't add `environments` blocks in arbitrary locations, and in general the log4j configuration can't be made very DRY since it has to occur in one closure. Here's what I think you were getting at:

```
import org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender

String commonPattern = "%d{yyyy-MMM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} [%t] %c %x%n %-5p %m%n"
environments {
   development {
      log4j = {
         info 'org.apache.',
              'org.tomcat.',
              'org.acegisecurity',
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails',
              'org.springframework',
              'org.hibernate'
         warn 'grails.app'
         debug 'org.hibernate.SQL',
               'org.hibernate.transaction'
      }
   }
   test {
      log4j = {
         root {
            error "stdout"
         }

         info 'org.apache.',
              'org.tomcat.',
              'org.acegisecurity',
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails',
              'org.springframework',
              'org.hibernate'
         warn 'grails.app'
      }
   }
   production {

      log4j = {
         String logDirectory = "${System.getProperty('catalina.base') ?: '.'}/logs"

         info 'org.apache.',
              'org.tomcat.',
              'grails.app',
              'org.acegisecurity',
              'org.codehaus.groovy.grails',
              'org.springframework',
              'org.hibernate'
         warn 'grails.app'

         appenders {
            file name: "errors", file: "${logDirectory}/pps-errors.log",
                 layout: pattern(conversionPattern: commonPattern)
            appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
               name:"roll", datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
               file:"${logDirectory}/pps-rolling.log",
               layout: pattern(conversionPattern: commonPattern))

            file name: "prod-errors", file: "${logDirectory}/pps-errors.log",
                 layout: pattern(conversionPattern: commonPattern)
            appender new DailyRollingFileAppender(
               name:"prod-roll", datePattern: "'.'yyyy-MM-dd",
               file:"${logDirectory}/pps-errors-daily.log",
               layout: pattern(conversionPattern: commonPattern))
         }

         root {
            info "prod-roll", "prod-errors", "roll", "errors"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I removed 'org.mortbay.log' since I doubt you're using Jetty - put it back if you are. Also 'grails.app' is listed under `info` and `warn`. And I removed the "stdout" appender from prod since that will dump to catalina.out and you've already configured file loggers.

The [app-info](http://grails.org/plugin/app-info) plugin has a feature where it will reverse-engineer the XML that could have been used to configure the equivalent logging configuration, if you were using the traditional log4j.xml approach. It's not exact but should be very close. I find it's very useful for debugging logging issues like this since even if you haven't used the XML file syntax you can compare the `Config.groovy` settings with what ends up in the XML and see what's missing, misconfigured, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try it out. Can you look at: http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2 Logging   Under "Environment-specific configuration"? Shouldn't it be possible to add the arbitrary environment blocks?

Comment: another note is that my previous configuration worked fine in development, and created all rolling files as expected.

Comment: Also, I haven't done anything with tomcat on the production server to make this work. Is there anything that I need to configure within tomcat to pick this up? Sorry, I am a newbie at this.

Comment: Also, not log4j.properties file is getting generated - is that the expected result?

Comment: No, there's no need to do anything in Tomcat - the war is self-contained. And nope, there's no log4j.properties file generated, since the configuration is done programmatically. That's why I suggested the app-info plugin - since there's no log4j file created, it's hard to know why things aren't working, or why they're not working as expected.

Comment: I am having trouble setting up your plugin. I have it installed, added the default configuration to Config.groovy: `grails.plugins.dynamicController.mixins....` and expected to be able to go to `http://localhost:8080/pps/adminManage/log4J` or `http://localhost:8080/pps/adminManage/` but it didn't work. Any other setup that I need? Thanks for your help.

Comment: I need more than "it didn't work" to help you out. 404? Blank page? Stacktrace?

Comment: It redirects me to my main page. I know you mentioned messing with the URL Mappings, but I don't know what to add as I am pretty new...Thanks.

Comment: Hey Burt - I got the plugin working, but the output of the estimated log4j.xml is not showing my custom appender. However, when I run the application in development mode I can see my custom appender file get generated correctly, so I am not sure what to make of it.  I will put the code in an edit above. I appreciate your continued help.

Comment: Still having a problem running in production. Please see edits 3 and 4 above.