# Logging configuration completely ignored in Config.groovy when deployed as a war?

Tags: grails, logging, log4j, war, slf4j

When I run my application with `run-app`, logging seems to work correctly. When I deploy as a WAR in tomcat, all my logging configuration is ignored, and I only see

`LOGLEVEL   logmessage`

Example:

`INFO   Hello world`

What could possibly be causing this? I tried deleting tomcat's logging.properties, but that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792420/grails-no-logging-in-tomcat

Comment: I get logging, but the format is wrong. My initial thought is that something else could be overriding the log4j configuration, which is probably different than no-logging whatsoever.

Comment: What is your pattern set to in the relevant appender?  The log4j closure of Config would be useful information.

Comment: I'm using the default Config.groovy and I see this behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even after wiping the logging entirely, I still see this in catalina.out, while my logs to a log file are written correctly. A plugin or library, likely, is screwing up my logging, but tracing it down at this point isn't worth it.